# when i use firebase.database().goOnline(); I get an error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

this is my code

```
admin.initializeApp({...});

var db = admin.database();
let ref = db.ref(...);

await ref.once("value",function () {...},);

firebase.database().goOffline();
firebase.database().goOnline();

 ref.on("value",function () {...},);
);
```

when i use firebase.database().goOnline(); I get an error

```
Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two ways of addressing Firebase.

You can access Firebase through:

1. Its client-side JavaScript SDK, in which case the entry point is usually called `firebase`.
2. Its server-side Node.js SDK, in which case the entry point is usually called `admin`.

Now you initialize `admin`, but then try to access `firebase.database()`. And since you did call `admin.initializeApp`  that's where the error comes from.

My guess is that you're looking for `admin.database().goOnline()` or `db.goOnline()`.

Also note that there is no reason to toggle `goOffline()`/`goOnline()` in the way you do now, and you're typically better off letting Firebase manage that on its own.